# Syntax Error only in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I get a syntax error only in IE11 on this line and i can't seem to pinpoint what the issue is. Its on line two `quizOptions.map((item, i) => {`

the error is: SCRIPT1002: Syntax Error (this was the edit)

I haven't seen any issues with this piece of code on any other browser.

```js
var quizOptions = cur_quizInfo.options;
quizOptions.map((item, i) => {
  var li = jQuery("<li>", {
    class: 'quiz_answers',
    text: item
  }).appendTo(buttonList);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ES6 [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) are not supported by Internet Explorer.

You could (probably) replace your example with this:

```
var quizOptions = cur_quizInfo.options;
quizOptions.map(function(item, i) {
  var li = jQuery("<li>", {
    class: 'quiz_answers',
    text: item
  }).appendTo(buttonList);
});
```

Comment: This was very helpful, and now i have a ton of code to look through to see what else may not be backwards compatible!

Comment: use a transpiler (like babel for example) ... write your code modern, run your code anywhere